# How to generate a blade with a custom command in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Is there any way to write a custom artisan command to generate a blade file when running command. Something similar to `php artisan make:auth` that one generates login and register blades!

I want to do something similar but havent found a good source on how I should do it ?

Comment: Have you looked here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#writing-commands?

Comment: Look at the code behind `make:auth` and see what it's doing to generate the files. Also, look into Artisan Development https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan to see where to start. Currently, there's not much we can help with; this is too broad for a suitable answer. Give it a try first and if you encounter errors, post a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plently of laravel libraries for scaffolding which will make view (blade template ). The syntax will be something like below

```
php artisan make:scaffold blog --schema="title:string,body:text"
```

Which will make model,view and controller .

have a look on
http://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/

https://github.com/laralib/l5scaffold